# Move a GameObject inches back (Left/Right/Back) after its been hit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using rigidbody with `isKinematic = true` and box collider with `isTrigger = true`. After the object collides with another, i move the object few inches behind from the collision. Is there a better way to achieve this using normalization? Such that it automatically calculates the distance from the GameObject to the Box Collider it collided with, and puts the user behind it. As sometimes x values needs to be changed and sometimes its z, also the values could be negative. What I have done is only a quick fix and does not work as implemented if the values are in negative.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class CollisionDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PlayerPos;


    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "CollideWithCam")
    {
        Debug.Log("HIT");
        StartCoroutine(MoveBack());
    }
    }

    IEnumerator MoveBack()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        PlayerPos.transform.position = new Vector3(PlayerPos.transform.position.x-1f, PlayerPos.transform.position.y, PlayerPos.transform.position.z-1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you've answered your own question in a sense when you ask if there is a better way and state that this is a quick fix. I would write a method that returns an appropriate vector and simply add it to the `position` vector using `+`. But what that vector should be will depend on contextual business logic that is appropriate for your game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to calculate position of your object relative to obstacle. After that you could modify relative vector as you like and apply it to player. Something like this:

```
    // No need to store GameObject when only Transform is needed.
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform player;
    
    // You can use [SerializeField] attribute to modify this value via inspector 
    // and keep it private.
    [SerializeField]
    private float bounceDistance = 1;
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // Instantly return if 'other' object has wrong tag. 
        // 'CompareTag' is mush faster than '==' operator.
        if (other.CompareTag("CollideWithCam")) return;

        // Might consider this value something like 'direction from the hit':
        Vector3 relativePosition = other.transform.position - transform.position;
        relativePosition = relativePosition.normalized * bounceDistance;
        
        // It is not clear what you trying to achieve.
        // Place the player behind the bounced object?
        StartCoroutine(MovePlayerTo(transform.position + relativePosition));

        // Or place the player behind the obstacle?
        StartCoroutine(MovePlayerTo(other.transform.position - relativePosition));
    }

    // Moving player to some position.
    private IEnumerator MovePlayerTo(Vector3 position)
    {
        // Defining variable with meaningful name instead of using magic value directly.
        float delay = 0.1f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        
        player.position = position;
    }
```

Note that in the example player is always appears at predefined distance from gameObject's center. If you need the exact collision point, it would be better to disable triggers and use `OnCollisionEnter`:

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        Vector3 hitDirection = other.contacts[0].normal;
        Vector3 hitPoint = other.contacts[0].point;
        StartCoroutine(MovePlayerTo(hitPoint - hitDirection));
    }
```

(You're gonna need to ignore irrelevant collisions as well).